# How to view video files in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't view video files from storage folder. My firebug shows ok response and showing some notice message. I think the problem is from

```
<source src="'+response.profileVideo+'" type="video/webm">.
```

Could you please check and help me to load video.

**JS**

```
$( "#view-from-server" ).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.get("/profile/video", function(response){
    $( "#profile-video" ).html('<video width="400" height="240" controls id="profile-video"><source src="'+response.profileVideo+'" type="video/webm"></video>');
});
```

**Controller Page**

```
public function index()
{
    $id                = Auth::user()->id;
    $details           = User::select('id', 'created_at')->find($id);
    $encrypt           = md5($details->id.$details->created_at);
    $directories       = Storage::files($encrypt);                                                  // Listout Files
    $webm              = preg_grep('/\/.*.webm$/', $directories);
    foreach($webm as $files){
        $split_folder_file = explode('/', $files);          //60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12/4135209867745277.webm
        $splitted_file     = end($split_folder_file);       //4135209867745277.webm
        /*$file              = Storage::disk('local')->get($encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file);
        return response($file, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'video/webm');*/
        $userdata          = 'userdata';
        $filenameresult    = storage_path().'/'.$userdata.'/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file;
        return response()->json(['profileVideo' => $filenameresult]);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm  btn-rounded btn-default" id="view-from-server">View Profile Video</button>
            <br>
   <div id="profile-video"></div>
 </div>
```

**Firebug response**

```
"C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage/userdata/60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12/8759253552413012.webm"
```

**Firebug Notice**

```
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

**Inspect with firebug**

When I inspect the html with firebug the result shows given below.

```
<div id="profile-video">
    <video width="400" height="240" controls="" id="profile-video">
    <source src="C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage/userdata/60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12/9462835104782046.webm" type="video/webm"/>
    </video>
    </div>
```

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your browser. Can you post the complete Firebug notice? Is there something about "unsupported type"?

Comment: @Tim, Thank you for your quick response. I have added a screenshot of firebug notice in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when you are requesting the webm-file it doesn't send the appropriate MIME type so Firefox throws the error that there is no file with a supported format/MIME type.

Since you are using apache, you have 2 options:

```
# /etc/apache2/mime.types
# add the following two lines to the file
audio/webm weba
video/webm webm
```

Or, using `.htaccess`

```
# .htaccess (within your public folder of laravel)
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba
```

Comment: I have added this in htaccess but notice is still showing and video is not viewing. I have added some section in my question "Inspect with firebug".  I have copied the source and paste in to another url video is not showing. So i changed the / slash to \ now video is showing in another tab. C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage\userdata\60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12\9462835104782046.webm.

Comment: So  $filenameresult    = storage_path().'/'.$userdata.'/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file; is not correct right?

Comment: Replace `./.` with `. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  .`

Comment: I used DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. But video is not working. But the path paste in the another url video is working. Really stuck on this stage

Comment: I think it's a absolute path problem.

Comment: Did you type the whole path (with `C:/` into your tab)? If that's the case, it won't be loaded through your XAMP stack but is loaded directly from your hard drive. Could you edit your complete .htaccess into your question?

Comment: Currently storage_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$userdata. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$encrypt. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$splitted_file; response is  C:\xampp\htdocs\ct\storage\userdata\60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12\9462835104782046.webm. I have added my htaccess

Comment: I don't see the type declaration in your htaccess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94312/discussion-between-sam-sam-and-tim).

Comment: In my apache it is enabled

Comment: If our discussion helped you solve your problem please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: My client needs files in storage folder. Absolute path can't support html5 video src yesterday we discussed that. So I had changed my code. At-present response is getting like http://ct.dev/storage/userdata/60e4dda43c442fe610bdbd4a0e5c3a12/94628351047‌​82046.webm. This is also not working. I have investigate the issue and found the exact reason, but I don't no how to resolve it. Reason is ct.dev is my localhost virtual name. In my apache config, www/ct/public alias is ct.dev. I tested with localhost path it works in my browser. I think some code need to replace public folder from ct.dev

Comment: Well, did you move the storage folder to the public folder?

Comment: No storage folder is in previous position

Comment: You can set your document root just to www/ct. But then you have to add /public to all your urls. Since I think this will be no possibility either you are left with moving the storage path to public. Your last option would be to move the logic to a function in your controller (which has access to the storage folder).

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thank yo so much for great support.